# Can $R=\{(1,6),(2,7),(3,8)\}$ be said transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Given a relation $R=\{(1,6),(2,7),(3,8)\}$.

It is clear that it is not reflexive and symmetric but can we say that it is transitive?

Comment: Yes, because in $\forall a,b,c \in X: (aRb \wedge bRc) \Rightarrow aRc$ the antecedent is always *false* and thus the conditional is *true*.

Comment: Yes. It’s vacuously transitive: there are no failure of transitivity, simply because there are no elements $x,y,z$ such that $x\mathrel{R}y\mathrel{R}z$ in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's transitive, for there is no $y$ such that $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ are elements of $R$. Therefore, if $(x,y),(y,z) \in R$, then so is $(x,z)$.